# Probability that out of $12$ objects placed in $20$ boxes, each box will contain no more than 2 objects

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I am trying to find the probability that among $20$ boxes and $12$ objects, there are no more than $2$ objects in any single box.

My work so far:

From previous experience I know that if the restriction is that we can only have at most $1$ object in a box, the probability will be given by $\frac{ \frac{20!}{8!}}{20^{12}}$.

So here I first noted that we have a total of $20^{12}$ ways to arrange the $12$ objects in $20$ boxes.

Now the number of ways to take the $12$ objects with at most $2$ objects per box,

$$\frac{20 \cdot 18 \cdot 16 \cdot 14 \cdot 12 \cdot 10 \cdot 8 \cdot 6 \cdot 4 \cdot 2}{12 \cdot 10 \cdot 8 \cdot 6 \cdot 4 \cdot 2}$$

and so we have the probability that $12$ objects are placed in $20$ boxes with no more than $2$ objects in any box as $$\frac{\frac{20 \cdot 18 \cdot 16 \cdot 14 \cdot 12 \cdot 10 \cdot 8 \cdot 6 \cdot 4 \cdot 2}{12 \cdot 10 \cdot 8 \cdot 6 \cdot 4 \cdot 2}}{20^{12}}$$.

Any hints or feedback would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this help you? https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3808288

Comment: Possibly. Here empty boxes are allowed, so I am not sure how to account for the case where a box is allowed to be empty.

Comment: Actually, I’m not sure about the generating function.

Comment: I think exponential generating functions would work. Based on the solution to the easier case with at most one object per box, it appears that the objects are distinguishable.

Comment: I was also considering $\frac{ \frac{20!}{8!} {12 \choose 2}}{20^{12}}$. I will try the exponential generating functions as well and see if I can find a solution.

Comment: Yes, this requires exponential generating functions. Specifically, the probability is $\frac{12!a_{12}}{20^{12}}$ where $a_{12}$ is the coefficient of $x^{12}$ of $$(1+x+x^2/2)^{20}$$ That is a much less friendly expression.

Comment: Yes it is. I appreciate the help. I will post a solution as soon as I can find/calculate this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand how you got your expression for the number of ways to distribute the balls.  If I am not mistaken this evaluates to $72576$.  However the number of distributions is far larger.

Let there be $k$ boxes with exactly two balls, and $12-2k$ boxes with exactly one ball, where $0\leq k\leq6$.  There are $\binom {20}k$ ways to choose the "double boxes" and then $\binom{20-k}{12-2k}$ ways to choose the single boxes.  Once we have chosen the boxes, we can line the balls up in any of $12!$ ways and distribute them into the chosen boxes in order.  However, in each of the double boxes, there are $2$ equivalent ways of placing the balls, so we must divide by $2^k$.

This gives $$12!\sum_{k=0}^6\binom{20}k\binom{20-k}{12-2k}2^{-k}=2631841659216000$$ which gives a probability of approximately $$0.6425394675820313$$ a result which is borne out by simulation.

Here's the simulation script, if anyone's interested:

```
from random import choices

trials = 100000
success = 0

for _ in range(trials):
    sample =choices(range(20), k=12)
    t = max(sample.count(k) for k in range(20))
    if t <= 2:
        success += 1
print(f'{success} successes in {trials} trials')
print(f'Success rate {success/trials}')
```